# Updating Kivy Label using a variable in Python

Tags: python, sockets, kivy

Basically I am trying to update a label in Kivy based on a variable from a socket program in Python.
The socket server sends a response and the label has to be update to reflect the response message which is variable strdata, I have tried just about everything but cant get it

*Main.py*

```
 #RECEIVE TEXT AND DECODE
 self.s.settimeout(20)
 data = self.s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE).decode()
 strdata = str(data)
 print(strdata)

 #Update label function
 def update_label(self):
    self.root.ids.special_label.text = strdata
```

*Main.kv*

```
SpecialGridLayout@GridLayout:
    cols: 1
    Label:
        text: "Special label"
        id :special_label
```

Answer (score 1):

If you define `strdata` as a `StringProperty` in the `SpecialGridLayout` class. then you can reference that property in your `kv`. That way, the `Label` text will be updated whenever you change `strdata`.

```
SpecialGridLayout@GridLayout:
    cols: 1
    Label:
        text: root.strdata
        id :special_label
```